# run bat with a copy of cmd.exe in another path

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a test.bat and a copy of cmd.exe (rename cmdnew.exe), both in a same folder.

**Question:**
How can i run test.bat with a specific "cmdnew.exe" (not with cmd.exe)? (how can i register the new path of shell cmdnew.exe)

**To be considered:**

1. I need to associate batch (.bat) file with the new cmdnew.exe
2. The cause of this question is because cmd.exe, regedit.exe and another GUI windows tools, "missing" from my Windows OS (not reason, and not related to the question). However, I must clarify that when I use the term "missing" it means that Windows does not find them, but applications are correctly listed in their directory. And if I try to manually run cmd.exe (from windows/system32) get the same message that: the operating system can not find cmd.exe
3. I need tu run my .bat with administrative privileges to fix the problems with my OS
4. I copied the new "cmdnew.exe" console to the Windows/system32 route, but when I opened is locked the command prompt (The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator. Press any key to continue...). And I can not change this restriction because applications "gpedit.msc" and "regedit.exe" are also "missing". In addition, this message should not go out because it is a local computer and the account has administrator privileges

Update: Jul 09

5. It is in personal computer and an administrative account. It is not connected to any network. Win 7 SP1 x64 OS. It is possible that this damage has been caused by malware; i'm not sure and neither is related to the question. Currently no presence of malware on the PC.

Thanks

Comment: Adding a copy of cmd.exe isn't going to sovle your actual problem, your system is corrupt, which means you should solve that problem first.

Comment: You are right. My system is corrupt. But i have a .bat to solve this problems, but i need to run, and i can't, because cmd.exe is missing. So i have a copy of cmd.exe in another path. thanks

Comment: Repair the OS so it works as it is suppose so **`SFC /SCANNOW`** from elevated command prompt perhaps to potentially resolve with a simple fix if so but won't know unless you try.

Comment: Already I tried that solution and reached 100% and did not notice anything

Comment: Can you do a **`START cmdnew.exe /k "<batch logic>"`** command and run logic with it that way?

Comment: In that way doesn't recognice my test.bat. (Even opening the console and calling the bat from within generate several error). I definitely include the path of the new console environment variables in my system to recognize it, but do not know how. That is my question

Comment: **Either** #1: `WinKey`+`R`  and run `cmdnew.exe /K` or run `cmdnew.exe /K fullpath\your.bat`. **Either** #2: pay your attention to the `comspec` variable (`set comspec` or `echo %comspec%`

Comment: I apologize. Previously I had said to user "PIMP_JUICE_IT", that the new "cmdnew.exe" console worked well in /windows/system32, but I was wrong. After restarting Windows 7, when opening "cmdnew.exe" displays the message: The administrator has disabled the command prompt.
And gpedit.exe and regedit.exe are "missing", so I can not "enable prompt". Sorry again

Comment: @BrianC - Load a Windows installation disk, load the registry Hive for your machine, make the required registry changes to enable the command prompt.

Comment: Hi Ramhound. Your solution is very good (could also reinstall the OS) but these solutions are too far from the original question. Anyway thank you very much for your concern.

Comment: Is this a locked down corporate machine or one that is infested with malware?

Comment: Hi Mokubai. It is a personal computer and the account has administrator privileges (Windows 7 SP1 x64). It is not connected to any network.  And it's possibly a malware has caused this damages (maybe. I don't know and this is not subject to the this topip. Currently there is no presence of malware on the PC

Comment: Open task manager and hold ctrl down while hitting file > start new task  This will open a elevated command prompt.  does that work?

Answer (score 0):

In Start Run you can type:

```
c:\your\complete\path\cmdnew.exe /c c:\your\complete\path\the.bat
```

Comment: doesn't work in this way

Comment: In addition, for the .bat work I run it with administrative privileges

Comment: Can you add any info on how/why you expect this to work Emilio?

Comment: Hi andy. I update the question